# Dynamic length name

Tags: lengths

I want to create something like in object, that saves it's own location in latex. Because I don't know how to create a objec in latex, I want to create a length with seperating name for each object. Like that: (Dont worry `\umlPositionX` and `\umlPositionY` is defined before)

```
\newcommand{\umlClass}[1]{
    \newlength{\umlPositionX#1}
    \setlength{\umlPositionX#1}{\umlPositionX}
    \newlength{\umlPositionY#1}
    \setlength{\umlPositionY#1}{\umlPositionY}
}
```

Now I want to get the position of the object like that:

```
\newcommand{\umlXPositionOf}[1]{\setlength{\umlPositionX}{\umlPositionX#1}
\newcommand{\umlYPositionOf}[1]{\setlength{\umlPositionY}{\umlPositionY#1}
```

But it is not possible, to create a length with dynamic name like that. I always get the error:

> Command \umlPositionX already defined.

I think it is because the #1 does not belong to the name of the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To patch a macro together in the way you seem to want one can use `\csname ...\endcsname`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newlength{\umlPositionX}
\newlength{\umlPositionY}
\setlength{\umlPositionX}{1pt}
\setlength{\umlPositionY}{2pt}
\newcommand{\umlClass}[1]{%
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\newlength{\csname umlPositionX#1\endcsname}%
     \noexpand\setlength{\csname umlPositionX#1\endcsname}{\umlPositionX}%
     \noexpand\newlength{\csname umlPositionY#1\endcsname}%
     \noexpand\setlength{\csname umlPositionY#1\endcsname}{\umlPositionY}}%
\temp%
}
\begin{document}
\umlClass{A}\the\umlPositionXA \the\umlPositionYA
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you marmot. That is what I was searching for. But how to acces the value dynamicly like I tried to explain with the seccond source example.

Comment: Never mind. I typed the `\csname` wrong. Because of that it didn't worked. For every else you have only to type \csname umlPosition#1\endcsname (without \noexpand), if you want to acces the value dynamicly.